# Hora Keep tool change column name

Tags: sql

I'm using Hora Keep Tool for SQL queries. When I use operations for example like

avg(age) to build the average value of a few values for the "group by" functionality, than it changes during the query in the output the original column name from "age" to "avg(age)".
I know that a string after the operation for example:

avg(age) age

would rename the column name, but I have a lot of rows, which I have to change than like this.

Is there a function which would not allow that during the query the column name would change from age to avg(age) ?

I would be happy if somenone could give me helpfully tips.
Thank you forward.

Comment: Search/Replace using a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ' as ' keyword in sql to name a column e.g

```
select user_name as username from users;
```

this query will result the column name as username.

```
---------------
USERNAME
---------------
hello
hello1
hello3
```